# Touch events on views inside UI Scroll View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have Implemented a UIScrollView on MainView as follows:

```
UIScrollView* scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-160, -540, 480, 1300)];
    [scrollView addSubview:self.MainView];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 2000);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

I have the following Views under MainView in Storyboard:

```
Main View ----> View1, View2
```

I want to implement touch events with View 1 and View 2 separately. For that I have the following code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapSlidersView1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSlidersActionView1:)];
    [self.View1 addGestureRecognizer:tapSlidersView1];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapSlidersView2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSlidersActionView2:)];
    [self.View2 addGestureRecognizer:tapSlidersView2];
```

And the corresponding event handlers:

```
- (void)tapSlidersActionView1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DropDownView1 animated:YES];
}

- (void)tapSlidersActionView2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DropDownView2 animated:YES];
}
```

The tap events does not seem to work at all. please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the frames of main view, view1 and view2?

Comment: Yes. Inside Main View I have two subviews in storyboard: View1 and View2

Comment: Simply create a invisibleView of same frame of self.view then add it to self.view but before that add a you temporaryView. So try it out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try following code and also every view is created programmatically..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *mainView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor ]];
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];

    UIScrollView* scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,mainView .bounds.size.width, mainView.bounds.size.height)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 2000);
    [mainView addSubview:scrollView];

    UIView *View1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 100, 100)];
    [View1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [scrollView addSubview:View1];

    UIView *View2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 150, 100, 100)];
    [View2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [scrollView addSubview:View2];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapSlidersView1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSlidersActionView1:)];
    [View1 addGestureRecognizer:tapSlidersView1];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapSlidersView2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSlidersActionView2:)];
    [View2 addGestureRecognizer:tapSlidersView2];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void)tapSlidersActionView1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    //your class
//    secViewController *DropDownView1=[[secViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DropDownView1 animated:YES];
}

- (void)tapSlidersActionView2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
//your class
//    secViewController *DropDownView2=[[secViewController alloc]init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DropDownView2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I cannot create views programmatically. Need them to come through storyboard

Comment: ok create a two view on your main view and make a tap gesture recognizer object and add them to first view and second view..dont forget to set a iboutlet for those views on main view

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you have to make sure that your view is touchable by enabling `userInteractionEnabled`.
Second, you need to declare `numberOfTapsRequired` for your tap event.

Then you have your code like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapSlidersView1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSlidersActionView1:)];
tapSlidersView1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

self.View1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.View1 addGestureRecognizer:tapSlidersView1];
```

Comment: @StackCoder Provide me more information. What have you changed? Did you make sure that the tap function is jumped in by using breakpoint? Is there any other view that lay on and cover up your View1 and View2?